# Compare multiple classes against a variable on a Jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I am using a query string to filter results of a list. The list items have multiple classes assigned to them as "topics" (which is one of the keys in the query string). I pull the multiple query topics into the array "queryTopics", which is then broken down into individual classes with "join()" and added to a jquery selector as a variable "chosenCategory" and then using "each()", I iterate through the list items. I would like to be able to pull the class names that matched the query "topics" from the list items and assign them to the variable "chosenTaxonomy".

Here is a part of my code that checks the list items along with a sample of the list item:

```js
function filterQuery(queryYear, queryTopics) {
    $("ul.mediaListing .errorMsg").remove();
    var chosenYear = queryYear.toString();
    var countShows = 0;
    var chosenCategory = queryTopics.join(", .");

    if (chosenCategory == "all") {
        chosenCategory = "mediaListingEntry";
    }
    if (chosenCategory == "mediaListingEntry" && chosenYear == "all") {
        $("ul.mediaListing").children("li").each(function(c) {
            countShows = countShows + 1;
            $(this).removeClass("filteredOut");
        });
    } else if (chosenYear == "all") {
        chosenYear = "mediaListingEntry";
        $("ul.mediaListing").children("li." + chosenYear + "." + chosenCategory).each(function(c) {
            var chosenTaxonomy = chosenCategory.replace(/[-.]+/g, ' ');
            $(this).find('.news-block-taxonomy').html(chosenTaxonomy);
            countShows = countShows + 1;
            $(this).removeClass("filteredOut");
        });
        $("ul.mediaListing").children("li:not(." + chosenYear + "." + chosenCategory + ")").each(function(c) {
            $(this).addClass("filteredOut");
        });
        var textYear = queryYear;
        $("ul.mediaListing").prepend("<h3 class='seachMsg'>Search results for " + chosenCategory.replace(/[.-]+/g, " ") + " in " + textYear + " years" + "</h3>");
    } else {
        $("ul.mediaListing").children("li." + chosenYear + "." + chosenCategory).each(function(c) {
            if (chosenCategory != "mediaListingEntry") {
                var chosenTaxonomy = chosenCategory.replace(/[-.]+/g, ' ');
                $(this).find('.news-block-taxonomy').html(chosenTaxonomy);
            }
            countShows = countShows + 1;
            $(this).removeClass("filteredOut");
        });
        $("ul.mediaListing").children("li:not(." + chosenYear + "." + chosenCategory + ")").each(function(c) {
            $(this).addClass("filteredOut");
        });
        var textYear = queryYear;
        $("ul.mediaListing").prepend("<h3 class='seachMsg'>Search results for " + chosenCategory.replace(/[.-]+/g, " ") + " in " + textYear + " years" + "</h3>");
    }
    if (countShows == 0) {

        var yearText = chosenYear;

        var categoryText = chosenCategory;
        if (chosenCategory == "all" || chosenCategory == "mediaListingEntry") {
            categoryText = "All Categories";
        }
        if (chosenYear == "all") {
            yearText = "All Years";
        }
        $("ul.mediaListing").append("<h3 class='errorMsg'>No matches for " + categoryText.replace(/[.-]+/g, " ") + " in " + yearText + " years" + "</h3>");
    }

    paginate();
}
```

```html
<ul class="news-list news-articles mediaListing">
    <h3 class="seachMsg">Search results for alumni,  academics in all news</h3>
    <li class="news-list-item mediaListingEntry 2016-17   faculty-&amp;-staff athletics filteredOut">
        <article class="news-block is-blue">
            <div class="news-block-holder">
            <strong class="news-block-taxonomy athletics">Athletics</strong>
            <div class="news-block-img" style="background-image: url(&quot;../assets/images/img-news-list-01.jpg&quot;); background-size: cover;">
                <img alt="News Image" src="../assets/images/img-news-list-01.jpg" style="display: none;">
            </div>
            <div class="news-block-body">
                <a class="news-block-link" href="2016-17/News.html">Turkey Sandwich</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `chosenYear` are `chosenCategory` are declared where? Please post the rest of the jQuery and since it seems that this is selector dependent, it'd be easier to figure out with HTML as well.

Comment: It would also help to format the code indentation to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you combine the year and categories with this:

```
.children("li." + chosenYear + "." + chosenCategory)"li." + chosenYear + "." + chosenCategory)
```

you end up with a selector like:

```
li.year.category1, .category2, .category3
```

Notice that the year class is only combined with the first category class, not with all of them.

Instead, you can do:

```
.children("li."+chosenYear).filter("."+chosenCategory)
```

Comment: this doesn't work for 
`$("ul.mediaListing").children("li:not(."+chosenYear).filter("."+chosenCategory)+")").each(function(c) {
   $(this).addClass("filteredOut"); }); `

Comment: Negating a combination of a selector and filter is more complicated. Why don't you just add `filteredOut` to everything, then remove it from the filtered items?

Comment: Barmar, to your original suggestion, I need the chosenYear to be the first class that is checked, with a check of any additional classes matching the selected topics. Right now, it will show all queries that match the chosenYear, but not check that the chosenCategory has at least one of the topics that were selected.

Comment: `.filter("."+chosenCategory)` performs the additional check of the categories.

Comment: As to your idea about adding filteredOut to all of the items, that won't work, due to refreshes of the query. I guess I need a way to make the:

`$("ul.mediaListing").children("li:not(." + chosenYear + "." + chosenCategory + ")").each(function(c) {
            $(this).addClass("filteredOut");
        });  `

Comment: Your code removes `filteredOut` from everything that matches the criteria, and adds it to everything that doesn't match the criteria (using `:not`). How is that different from adding it to everything, then removing it from everything that matches the criteria?

Comment: You are correct Bamar! That part now works. Now is there a way to pull what topics matched the classes on the list items? I would like to display which "topic or topics" in the variable chosenTaxonomy

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but it sounds like a different problem. You need to show an example of what you want the result to look like.